# Failed to install/uninstall Async CTP on windows XP machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-ctp

I've run the installation of Async CTP on Windows XP machine, though 
i do not see any effect. Nither on VS2010pro C# compiler nor on installed
programs list.

That would not bother me much, but installing MVC3 RC2 failes since 
its incompatible with Async CTP.

I've found no way to overcome the problem. For some reason Async CTP 
does not install correctly, and thus cant be uninstalled.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

From the "Uninstall Instructions.rtf":

> The Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP
>   is installed as two updates:
>   1)    .NET Framework 4.0 update called
>   ".NET Framework Async CTP"
>   2)    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 update
>   called "Microsoft Visual Studio Async
>   CTP"
>  To uninstall go to
>   Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> View installed updates. You will need to uninstall both updates.

Comment: Hello, Ed thanks for your answer. In Windows XP i do not have Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> View installed updates this probably belongs to Vista or 7. I've reinstalled the VS2010 from scratch still could not get rid of the CTP...

Answer (score 2):

Under XP on the "Add remove programs" dialog check in the "Show updates" checkbox.
You should see the updates in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found searching in the registry.

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Client\setup.exe /uninstallpatch {B81081A3-91D8-3B0C-8AC5-1B51746D26C5} /parameterfolder Client

Comment: Also: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /package {D6B15AE6-B052-363E-B6BB-C4714CBA6509} /uninstall {3D707CB8-B58F-3B0D-9F4C-93AF3CE8EAE2} /qb+ REBOOTPROMPT=&quot;&quot;